# VBA converting Excel to PDF with non-standard font

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, fonts

I'm trying to export an excel sheet to PDF using ExportAsFixedFormat, the code I have is creating the PDF but it substitutes the Myriad Pro from my Excel file with a standard font in the converted pdf.

The export code is below:

```
awb.Sheets("PIN").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                 fileName:=strFileName, _
                 Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                 IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                 IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                 OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Is there any way I can force Adobe to use the fonts I have set instead of reverting to standard fonts? When I convert a single sheet to PDF manually it works fine.

Comment: `When I convert a single sheet to PDF manually it works fine.` How do you convert it? `File|Print` or `File|SaveAs`?

Comment: I have an Acrobat add-in for excel that converts to pdf - in the preferences it has an option 'rely on system fonts' which can be unticked.

Comment: So how does this Add-In Work? Do you need to click on `File|Print`?

Comment: AFAIK, `.ExportAsFixedFormat` doesn't use Adobe

Comment: To convert using the add-on - I have an acrobat tab in my excel menu, I select that and there is convert to pdf option, that then saves the selected worksheets are pdf files, using the preset page breaks etc.

Comment: @GullitsMullet, `ExportAsFixedFormat` uses an MS supplied library to perform the export.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Acrobat Distiller if it's installed on every machine that will be using your file...  If that's the case you do it like this:

First, in the printer settings for Distiller you'll need to disable the option `Rely on system fonts only; do not use document fonts` or you'll get an error message.

Second, in the `Tools` menu of your VB Editor, go to the `References` option.  You'll need to find and check the `Acrobat Distiller` reference.

## Code:

```
Sub ExportPDF()
    Dim acro As New ACRODISTXLib.PdfDistiller6
    Dim wk As Worksheet
    
    Const opFile As String = "C:\test\test.ps"
    Const PDFFile As String = "C:\test\test.pdf"
    Const PrinterName As String = "Adobe PDF"
    
    Set wk = Sheet1
    
    wk.PrintOut ActivePrinter:=PrinterName, PrintToFile:=True, PrToFileName:=opFile
    
    acro.FileToPDF opFile, PDFFile, ""
    
End Sub
```

This should give a good starting point.

**Note:** The object name for Distiller and the printer name might be different for different versions of Distiller.

Comment: Thanks, will give that a go later :)

Comment: I've managed to adapt that to produce a PDF file but now I'm getting the issue that made me revert to the exportasfixedformat issue - when I try to convert one of my excel sheets using the above method I get an `%%[ Warning: Empty job. No PDF file produced. ] %%` error, there is definitely content in the worksheet and the method works fine on almost identical excel sheets we use - any ideas?

Comment: Try it with a standard print out and see what you get.  My guess is that your print areas got weird.